# Transpose dataframe with cells as sum over columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the following form:

```
          x_30d   x_60d   y_30d   y_60d 
127         1.0     1.0     0.0     1.0
223         1.0     0.0     1.0     NaN
1406        1.0     NaN     1.0     0.0
2144        1.0     0.0     1.0     1.0
2234        1.0     0.0     NaN     NaN
```

I need to transform it into the following form (where each cell is the sum over each column above):

```
        30d     60d
x         5       1 
y         3       2
```

I've tried using dictionaries and splitting columns. melting the dataframe, along with transposing it, etc. but I cannot seem to get the correct pattern.

To make things slightly more complicated, here are some actual column names that have a mix of forms for date ranges: `PASC_new_aches_30d_60d`, `PASC_new_aches_60d_180d`, ... `PASC_new_aches_360d`, ..., `PASC_new_jt_pain_180d_360d`, ...

Comment: kindly share your updated dataframe with the complicated columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
In [131]: new = df.sum()

In [132]: new.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
                            new.index.str.extract(r"^(.*?)_(\d+d.*)$"))

In [133]: new
Out[133]:
0               1
PASC_new_aches  30d_60d     5.0
                60d_180d    1.0
x               30d         3.0
PASC_new_aches  360d        2.0
dtype: float64

In [134]: new.unstack()
Out[134]:
1               30d  30d_60d  360d  60d_180d
0
PASC_new_aches  NaN      5.0   2.0       1.0
x               3.0      NaN   NaN       NaN
```

- sum as usual per column
- original's columns are now at the index; need to split them

  - using a regex here: `^(.*?)_(\d+d.*)$`

    - `^`: beginning
    - `(.*?)` anything, but greedily until...
    - `_(\d+d.*)` ...underscore followed by d pattern; also anything after it
    - `$` the end
- while splitting we extracted before & after of an underscore with `(...)`s
- make them the new index (a multiindex now)
- unstack the inner level to become new columns, i.e., the parts after "_"

noting that those "1" and "0" at the top left are the "name"s of the axes of the frame; 0 is that of `df.index`, 1 is of `df.columns`. They are there due to pd.MultiIndex.from_frame. Can remove by `.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)`.

Comment: @horcle_buzz You can still use the same overall idea, just need to change how you're doing the split. What would you want exactly? Maybe `'PASC_new_aches', '30d_60d'` for that first one? Then you could use `.split("_(?=\d)", n=1, expand=True)`

Answer (score 1):

one option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd

(df
.agg(['sum'])
.pivot_longer(
     index = None, 
     names_to = ('other', '.value'), 
     names_sep='_')
)
  other  30d  60d
0     x  5.0  1.0
1     y  3.0  2.0
```

The `.value` determines which parts of the columns remain as column headers.

If your dataframe looks complicated (based on the columns you shared):

```py
      PASC_new_aches_30d_60d  PASC_new_aches_60d_180d  PASC_new_aches_360d  PASC_new_jt_pain_180d_360d
127                      1.0                      1.0                  0.0                         1.0
223                      1.0                      0.0                  1.0                         NaN
1406                     1.0                      NaN                  1.0                         0.0
2144                     1.0                      0.0                  1.0                         1.0
2234                     1.0                      0.0                  NaN                         NaN
```

then a regex, similar to @MustafaAydin works better:

```py
(df
.agg(['sum'])
.pivot_longer(
     index=None, 
     names_to = ('other', '.value'), 
     names_pattern=r"(\D+)_(.+)")
)
              other  30d_60d  60d_180d  360d  180d_360d
0    PASC_new_aches      5.0       1.0   3.0        NaN
1  PASC_new_jt_pain      NaN       NaN   NaN        2.0
```